# How do I get search result from content with display:none - SharePoint

Tags: search, sharepoint

On a page I have added a content editor with text that has display none. How can I make the text with display:none  searchable with SharePoint search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make hidden text from Content Editor Web Parts show up in search results, you need to use internal or external styling, not inline styles on the text itself.

The text below will be shown in search results:

```html
<style>
.hidden { display: none; }
</style>

<p class="hidden">This text will be indexed by the search engine.</p>
```

This text, however, will not be shown in search results:

```html
<p style="display: none">This text will not be indexed by the search engine.</p>
```

In addition, you need to update the *Search and Offline Availability* settings for your site to make sure the web part is actually indexed. To do this, go to *Site Settings* and look under the *Search* category, then click *Search and Offline Availability*. On the following page, you need to set *Indexing ASPX Page Content* to *Always index all Web Parts on this site*. Please read the description for that setting to be aware of the potential side effects, though.

I found this solution [here](https://ebudur.wordpress.com/2014/05/20/hiding-content-from-search-results-displaynone-and-noindex/). I have tested it on SharePoint 2013 and can confirm that it works.

Comment: Thank you so much! Change the settings to "Always index all Web Parts on this site" fixed my problem.